# Echo a single number to all .dll files in a directory

Tags: text, batch-file, echo

In a folder named "drops" I have 3 .dll files. I am looking for a piece of code that can echo the number 0 to each .dll file without having to echo them individually. Basically, I don't want to have to open up each file and change the number to 0... laziness ensues!

```
for /f %%G IN (C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\CMDRPG\player\inventory\drops\*.dll) DO echo 0
```

I have tried using for. Is my code wrong? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Title didn't have anything to do with my question :D

Comment: Where is the zero going?  You seem to be asking to replace the content of each of the DLL files?  DLL files don't commonly just have a single number as the content.  Your title is asking to delete a folder though

Comment: Why does title talks about deleting folder and question body doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy

```
forfiles /p "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\CMDRPG\player\inventory\drops" /m "*.dll" /c "cmd.exe /c echo 0 > @path"
```

That will do it. Also, in ou code, add `> %%G` Thats the only mistake I found.

Mona

Comment: just a silly question: is it a good idea, to overwrite (or change) any DLLs?

Comment: @Stephan I am generating the .dll files myself, so there is no harm in overwriting them.

Answer (score 0):

Drop `/F`, use

```
FOR %%G IN (C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\CMDRPG\player\inventory\drops\*.dll) DO ECHO 0
```

`/F` will try to open file `*.dll`.